# vmware + xcode + phonegap + make arhive = buffer overflow

Tags: xcode, cordova

I used xcode+phonegap on virtual machine. When i try make arhive of any project i get an error like this:

> error:
>   '/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**TESTING**-avvoxtuipponnbeqgsiwblbbidxq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/**TESTING**/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app/**TESTING**.app' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025)

Help me! What could be the problem and how to increase the buffer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem just now.

It turned out I accidentally dragged the project's product itself into the "Copy Bundle Resources" section.

So xcode is trying to recursively build the product, so it can add the product itself recursively as a resource for itself.

Remove the product itself from "Copy Bundle Resources" section solved it for me.